# How to filter on a column that has both float and datetime

Tags: pandas, datetime, object, floating-point

I have a column in my dataframe that has both `datetime` values and `float` values. How do I filter out the `float` values? I have tried the following:

```
import datetime

a = pd.DataFrame([10.0,datetime.datetime.now(),20.0])

a = a[a.dtype!=float]
```

That does not work because pandas says the entire column is datatype object. The goal would be to get rid of the 10 and the 20 and just leave the current time value.

Comment: You could coerce the conversion to datetime, and drop the irrelevant values : ``pd.to_datetime(a[0], errors='coerce').dropna()``

Comment: You can map type to the values, e.g. `df[df[0].map(type) != float]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly suspect that the floats that you see are NaN values. So, I would suggest this:

```
a_float_free = a.dropna()
```

On the other hand, if my doubt is wrong you can then filter out the floats using

```
import datetime

a = pd.DataFrame([10.0,datetime.datetime.now(),20.0])

a_float_free = a[a[0].apply(lambda x: not isinstance(x, float))]
```

PS: In your dummy example in the question, you have given `int`s instead of `float`s. I took the liberty of changing them to `float`